# How can I connect a for loop from a business class to another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I was asked to, write an application that will enable a vendor to see what earnings he can expect to make based on what percentage he marks up an item. Allow the user to input the wholesale item price. In a tabular form, show the retail price of the item marked up at 5%, 6%, 7%, 8%, 9%, and 10%. I wrote this program in a windows form application but I am having trouble with connecting my for loop from one class to output on the form from the other class. Here is my code:
This is my business class:

```
namespace RetailPrice
{
// Business Class 
class Wholesale
{

    decimal wholesale;

    //Constructor
    public Wholesale(decimal sale)
    {
        this.wholesale = sale;
    }

    public string GetWholesalePrice(string priceIn)
    {
        decimal price = decimal.Parse(priceIn);
        string priceOut = string.Empty;
        //for loop for the class wholesale to set
        for (int i = 5; i < 11; i++)
        {
            decimal percent = i / 100;
            decimal wsale = price * (decimal.Parse(i.ToString()) / decimal.Parse("100"));
            priceOut += string.Format(" Markup of {0} percent is {1:c}\n", i, (decimal.Parse(i.ToString()) / decimal.Parse("100")));
        }
        return priceOut;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my form class:

```
namespace RetailPrice
{
public partial class WholeSalePrice : Form
{
    public WholeSalePrice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the intial value for Whole sale price
        Decimal wholesalePrice = 0;
        wholesalePrice = Decimal.Parse(TxtWholeSale.Text);

        //Create an instance of Wholesale that takes wholesaleprice
        Wholesale wsale = new Wholesale(wholesalePrice);
        
        LblOutput.Text = (wholesalePrice) + wsale.GetWholesalePrice(TxtWholeSale.Text);
}
}
```

Here is what my form looks like:[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9icRB.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not the best at posting question on this site either and have read how to make a good post, but any advice on how to improve my post is more than welcomed.
I need the form to post the markup from the calculation in the for loop. Here is where it needs to be done I think.

```
     // Set the intial value for Whole sale price
    Decimal wholesalePrice = 0;
    wholesalePrice = Decimal.Parse(TxtWholeSale.Text);

    //Create an instance of Wholesale that takes wholesaleprice
    Wholesale wsale = new Wholesale(wholesalePrice);
```

Here is what the output looks like: [The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q8cJ.png)

So my calculations are not working as I need the amount he made from it like how you would gain 5 dollars for every 100 he sold it for at 5%

Comment: So what is your question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you're doing exactly that, hence your question being unclear. What about it isn't working?

Comment: It does not do the calculations correctly

Comment: My Question is how to get the calculations to pop up on my form. It outputs like this: when I enter 500 it says the markup is .05 while correct it needs to show the amount he gained from the sale

Comment: Your question does not indicate that. If it's not "doing the calculations correctly" then logically there must be a problem with the code. Without any information about your input, expectations, and what's wrong, there is no way to answer the question. You know what you're trying to achieve. We don't.

Comment: Also, why are you doing `decimal.Parse("100")` and not simply writing `100m`? Likewise `decimal.Parse(i.ToString())` instead of `(decimal)i`. Don't involve strings when they are not needed.

Comment: My teacher said I need to write the decimal.Parse("100") and the decimal.Parse(i.ToString()). I am not sure why they are needed

Comment: Your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of problems with your code.

```
public string GetWholesalePrice(string priceIn)
{
    decimal price = decimal.Parse(priceIn);
    string priceOut = string.Empty;
    //for loop for the class wholesale to set
    for (int i = 5; i < 11; i++)
    {
        decimal percent = i / 100m;
        decimal wsale = price * percent;
        priceOut += string.Format(" Markup of {0} percent is {1:c}\n", i, wsale);
    }

    return priceOut;
}
```

1. You were calculating percent with integer division - `5 / 100 = 0`. I replaced this with 100m (the m denotes the decimal type) so that it calculates correctly.
2. You were calculating wsale but not using the result.
3. You could further improve this using [`decimal.TryParse(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle situations where priceIn isn't a valid number.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question if you have the time. Now it just outputs Markup of 5% is $25 at 500. How would I get it to output $525?

Comment: @Chad In future questions (where applicable), I recommend including your input, expected output and your actual output. It makes it much easier to understand where your code might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, John. I will remember to do that

Comment: I'd recommend changing the `priceIn` parameter and return value to be a decimal too.  There is no reason to write a maths function that operates on strings.  Choose the most appropriate type and let the caller deal with wrangling what they have into that.